# How to avoid inserting special characters in a SQL Server column?

Tags: sql-server, string

I need to create a restriction in SQL Server that prevents inserting special characters into the `firstname` column.

I have tried to create it this way:

```
ALTER TABLE [CTPlatform].[Users] WITH NOCHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_Users_Firstname] 
        CHECK ([FirstName] LIKE '[A-Z]')
GO
```

But it only allows me to enter one character, example: 'A', 'J', but I need it to allow me to enter 'Jhon', 'Maria'

Comment: You need a bit of inverted logic for this: `[FirstName] NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]%'`. Note that an accent-insensitive collation will still allow characters like `é` this way. I would, incidentally, question the logic of not allowing "special" characters in people's names -- names are pretty special, and you're not going to be making friends with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
ALTER TABLE [CTPlatform].[Users] 
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Users_Firstname 
       CHECK (FirstName NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%')
```

Comment: Thanks friend. It effectively allows me to add strings in the range of A-Z preventing special characters from being added.